# How to convert Html content into plain text in Tailwind and postcss

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, postcss, html-react-parser

I'm not able to parse html-content in react, which is actually tailwind and postcss specific issue because i have used same code on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/parse-html-xkh2d) which is working fine without tailwind CSS styling.

**Note:** I have tested this on my local-computer with and without tailwind, i have faced same issue

**App.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState('<p>asdfsadf</p><ul><li>asdfsdf</li><li>sdcas</li></ul>');
  return (
    <div className="m-10">{parse(text)}</div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Expected Output**
[image]

**Actual Output**
[image]

Whether there is another way to convert html into plain-text when using tailwind for styling in react

Comment: Did you create the app on your pc using `create-react-app`?

Comment: yes, actually it is working fine without tailwind.

Comment: You should add how you are using tailwind with the parser to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState(
    '<p>asdfsadf</p><ul><li>asdfsdf</li><li>sdcas</li></ul>'
  );
  return <div className="m-10" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />;
};

export default App;
```

Result https://react-v29quj.stackblitz.io/

Comment: I don't know why my answer is down voted but I know that result is what you look for. https://react-v29quj.stackblitz.io

Comment: I have used atleast 4-5 method(including above) to convert html to plain-text, It is working fine without tailwind

Comment: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-type By default Tailwind css set list style at none.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with HTML parsing.

Tailwind has a [preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight) stylesheet. One of the things that happen is that [list bullets are removed](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#lists-are-unstyled).